# sending HTMLcollection to database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

so I have this table with `contenteditable` `divs`, when a user inputs something in a `div` they have to click a button that collects all the content of the `divs` and stores them into `Var OBJ`.

```
document.getElementById("done_editing").addEventListener("click", get_values);
var OBJ = [];

function get_values() {
  let divobj = document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable=true]')
  for (var i = 0; i < divobj.length; i++) {
    OBJ.push(divobj[i].textContent)
    //console.log(OBJ)  
  }

  OBJ = OBJ.filter(item => item)
  console.log(OBJ)
```

I want to send the values inside of `var OBJ` to a Database. I cant Wrap my head around on how to do this . It is not your average form so I guess I have to use ajax but I have no experience with ajax. this is what i Have for ajax.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: { arraykey: OBJ },
    success: function (response) {
      alert('succes')
      // You will get response from your PHP page (what you echo or print)
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  })

}
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction on how to use ajax and how to configure the php file ?

php file :

```
 //Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$data = isset($_POST['arraykey']);
if ($data)
{
  $array = $_POST["arraykey"];
  echo $array;
  echo " is your array";
} 
else 
{
  $array = null;
  echo "no array supplied";
}



/*$data = isset($_POST['OBJ']);

print_r($_POST);
*/
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

- the `var_dump($_POST);` returns a `array(0) { }`
- update: ajax seems to succeed but no array is passed to php.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are multiple `divs` you can use `array` to add mutliple values to it and send the same to ajax.

Demo Code :

```js
document.getElementById("done_editing").addEventListener("click", get_values);

var OBJ = [];

function get_values() {
  let divobj = document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable=true]')
  for (var i = 0; i < divobj.length; i++) {
    OBJ.push(divobj[i].textContent); //add in array 

  }
  console.log(OBJ)
  //your ajax call
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {
      OBJ: OBJ //pass array to php 
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert("something");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
<div contentEditable="true"></div>

<button id="done_editing">Done</button>
```

Your php will look like below :

```
  <?php
    // You should call this first
     session_start();
    $data = isset($_POST['arraykey']);
     if ($data)
       {
       $_SESSION['arraykey'] = $_POST["arraykey"];//putting aray value in session
       echo  $_SESSION['arraykey'];
       echo " is your array";
        } 
        else 
        {
        echo "no array supplied";
       }

        ?>
```

Comment: hi thank you for your feedback in the meantime I did what you did but it seems like my php is not receiving anything. I will update my code.

Comment: does your browser console shows any error? your code seems ok to me.Also ,not even `echo "no array supplied";` is sent back ? can you do `alert(response)` inside your ajax success function? and see what it gives?

Comment: no error in console when i browse to my php file it states my else statement 'no array supplied' or am I stupid and can you not browse to the  php file with url and expext the array to show ?

Comment: no you cannot go to php directly :) whatever will be  under `echo` will send back to your ajax .if you want to use this array somewhere simply save that in `session`  .

Comment: when I used the `alter(response)` it says something like `<br/> <b> Notice</b> : array to string conversion in <b> 'mypath to php file </b> on line <b> 17 </b <br/> array is your array`

Comment: yes that will be response sent from your php to ajax .Use `session` at your php side to use anywhere

Comment: `session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['arraykey'])){
    $array = $_SESSION['arraykey'];
    echo $array;
    echo " is your array";
}else {$array = NULL; 
    echo " no array supplied";
}` gives no array supplied

Comment: updated my code , now you can use `$_SESSION['arraykey'];` anywhere until you unset it .

Comment: Thank you very much !